# Why aren't these unordered list items containing images displaying in a horizontal row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an unordered list of items containing images in a row. I'm trying to make a carousel, so that only one image is visible on the screen at a time. Problem is the list items are not displaying inline as I want them to. I've only shown the html and css here because the problem is the images in the unordered list not displaying in a horizontal line.

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        section.hero {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 24px;
            color: #3f3f3f;
            width: 100%;
            height: 93vh;
            background-color: #F9CDAD;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .left {
            float: left;
            width: 2%;
            height: 75%;
            padding-top: 15%;
        }
        .hero_images {
            height: 85%;
            width: 96%;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        #landmark {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
        }
  #landmark ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      height: 100%;
  }
  #landmark ul li {
            display: inline;
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%;  
  }

        .clear-left {
            clear: left;
        }
        .left a { text-decoration: none; color: #3f3f3f; }
```

```html
    <section class="hero">

        <div class="left"><a href="#"><h1 id="left"><</h1></a></div>

        <div class="hero_images">

            <div id="landmark">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="https://buildingontheword.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cat.jpg" /></li>
     <li><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/small-orange-kitten-lie-on-the-bed-picture-id465257035?k=6&m=465257035&s=612x612&w=0&h=ao7AXh-3zDStrPYWZFbbp5kI-wpW8M1y2BHwYcXjvuA=" /></li>
    </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        
        <div class="left"><a href="#"><h1 id="right">></h1></a></div>

        <h2 id="pos" class="clear-left">Hello</h2>

    </section>
```

Comment: inline-block on the li not inline

Comment: When I try this on my page it squishes the li elements to fit inside the visible view box... I put height and width of 100% on li but with this method they are 50% each

Comment: you are setting width/height so you need at least inline-block ... then I don't know what you aim to achieve but width/height doesn't work on inline element

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after poking at it for 2+ hours I -think- I got a working version of what you intended. My apologizes for some reworking on the HTMl, needed to get the divs to work a certain way for easy resizing and positioning purposes. It does work correctly straight off my localhost with no issues though.

```js
var currentPicture;
var pictures;

function nextPicture() {
  currentPicture++;
  if(currentPicture >= pictures.length) {
    currentPicture = 0;
  }
 
  changeDisplay();  
}

function previousPicture() {
  currentPicture--;
  if(currentPicture < 0) {
    currentPicture = pictures.length - 1;
  }
 
  changeDisplay();  
}

function changeDisplay() {
  for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    if(i == currentPicture) {
      $(pictures[i]).show();

    } else {
      $(pictures[i]).hide();
    }

  }
}

$(function (){
  currentPicture = 0;
  pictures = $("li");
  changeDisplay();

  $("#left").click(previousPicture);
  $("#right").click(nextPicture);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
        
.hero {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 93vh;
  background-color: #F9CDAD;
  text-align: center;
}
.caravel {
  display: flex;
  height: 90%;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
.hero_images {
  flex: 8;
}
.hero_images ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.hero_images ul li {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.clear-left {
  text-align: center;
}
.left a { 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #3f3f3f;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="hero">
      <div class="caravel">
        <div class="left"><a href="#"><h1 id="left"><</h1></a></div>

        <div class="hero_images">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="https://buildingontheword.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cat.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/small-orange-kitten-lie-on-the-bed-picture-id465257035?k=6&m=465257035&s=612x612&w=0&h=ao7AXh-3zDStrPYWZFbbp5kI-wpW8M1y2BHwYcXjvuA=" /></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="left"><a href="#"><h1 id="right">></h1></a></div>
      </div>
      <h2 id="pos" class="clear-left">Hello</h2>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```